# Authenticate .Net 4.x apps using .Net core 2.2 Web API

Tags: authentication, webforms, asp.net-core-webapi

I am making a token authentication Web API in .Net Core 2.2, haven't decided if I should use OWIN or identityserver4 yet.

On our intranet we have many applications made in .Net 4.5 and some recent ones in .Net Core 2.2.

Is it possible to authenticate them all on .Net Core 2.2 Web API?

Comment: Your web api is identity server which issues/validate token , it won't care your client app is using .net core or .net framework . Just send username/password to your web api , after get access token from api if credential is correct , create authentication cookie to make user sign in in client app .

Answer (score 0):

You can use IdentityServer4 running in a .NET Core 2.2 application, which can provide your token authentication for all your applications. This uses OAuth2 which will give you a token which can be set in HTTP Request Authorization header on subsequent HTTP requests to your API. You don't need to use cookies at all.

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html